# Add Firebase App per package?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I am attempting to add Firebase Analytics and Crash Reporting to my app. I added the app in the Firebase Console. I made the updates to gradle and added the firebase core and crash reporting libs as dependencies.

My app is broken into multiple subprojects. Each has a slightly different package name:

```
app/org.mythtv.android.app
tv/org.mythtv.android.tv
presentation/org.mythtv.android.presentation
domain/org.mythtv.android.domain
data/org.mythtv.android.data
```

app and tv are two high-level subprojects that separate the app from the android tv version, presentation is common components for the 2 previous interface layers, domain encapsulates the interaction with common logic when dealing with data, and data is where the interaction with the backend occurs.

They all share a common package: org.mythtv.android
The application id is org.mythtv.android.

I created an app in the Firebase Console based on org.mythtv.android and added the google-services.json to the root of app and tv. I then wanted to track the crash reports in the other layers as well. Gradle fails to build at this point as it can't find packages org.mythtv.android.presentation and org.mythtv.android.data. These are both Android Library subprojects. data is just a java subproject.

Does the Firebase console need to have a separate app per package and each needs its own separate google-services.json?  Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose?

Comment: I have a bunch of questions - please answer all of them.  :-)  What is your intent for having separate app and tv projects?  Do you build and publish them both to the same app on the market, but targeting different devices?  Can you describe the diffs you made across all these projects for Firebase.  Where exactly did you apply the google services plugin?  Can you show more specific log messages in the build failure?

Comment: @DougStevenson The app is separate from the android tv version because I have to support back to SDK 14. Adding Leanback requires a minimum of SDK 17.They are published under the same app. When I added the google-services.json and gradle dependencies in the lower projects is when I saw the error and gradle wouldn't build the project. I have already reverted those changes, but it comes down to I added the same google-services.json in all projects and the gradle plugin to those Android Library projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you already got to the root of the problem, which is that you're only supposed to copy the google-service.json apply the google services plugin to application projects, not library projects.  The plugin wants to make some changes that are only relevant for apps.

To help others with the same problem, the error message looks like this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.google.mylibrary'
```

Where "mylibrary" is the name of your own library project.

To be honest, I think the plugin should detect if it's being applied to a library project and fail instead with a better message, so I'll see if we can get that remedied.

As an aside, you may want to consider merging your two app projects into a single app project with two different flavors, one for app and the other for tv.  They can then share everything by default, but have separate configurations to target different API levels and even have different sets of resources, assets, manifest items, and even independent code, if you're careful.  This should simplify the structure of your project.  You can read build variants here:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: I will check out that link. I recently did a major refactor to clean up the architecture so that it would promote more separation between the logical layers and ease automated testing. If the variants promote this, as well as let me support back to SDK 14 with the Leanback Library, I will schedule another refactor.

Comment: if you could take a look at my repo. Any recommendations on migrating to new build system would be greatly appreciated. I found that I couldn't upload both APKs in one listing as I thought I could: https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythtvPlayerForAndroid

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics reports based on the application package name. The package name is not related to the packages you use for your Java classes. The two are independent. The application package name is used by Android to identify your app (for update for example) and can not be changed once you release your app. If you are using gradle you can find it in your `app/build.gradle` as applicationId value or in your AndroidManifest.xml `package` attribute.